# Google analytics events shows up in the realtime events but doesn't shows up in behavior Events tab

Tags: node.js, google-analytics, universal-analytics

When i send an event to google analytics it shows up in the real time. But not available in behavior events tab (Even after 3 days). So, I am not able to make of it in reports.

[image]

```
const ua = require("universal-analytics");
const config = require("../config");

const analytics = ua("UA-1xxxxxxx-x", "ae21bb3e-0e53-4054-89d6-a5bbecc485e7", {
  requestOptions: {
    proxy: config.externalHttpProxy
  }
});

analytics.event(
    {
       "eventCategory": "Team",
       "eventAction": "ADD_USER_TO_TEAM",
       "cd1": "team-new",
       "cd3": "user1",
       "cd4": "2020-09-02T17:07:48",
       "cd5": "30"
    },
    err => {
      if (err) {
        log.error("Error occurred while sending event to ga", err);
      }
    }
);
```

Am i missing anything here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I uncheck "Bot Filtering" checkbox in view settings, all those events started showing in the behavior events tab after 12hrs.

[image]

Note: We can send only max 500 events per session. If we post more than 500 events, those were not processed. So, it will not be visible in behavior tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add Document location URL parameter (dl) to the event hit: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#dl

Comment: "dl" is required for pageview. I am sending it as event

Comment: I know, but with the measurement protocol there are some parameters that allow you not to be recognized as a bot, so you don't have to uncheck bot filtering. One of these is "dl" (or even just "dh"), if it doesn't work with just this extra parameter there are others to add such as ip, user agent, screen resolution, etc ... This allows you to send hit with measurement protocol and use the view's spam filter instead of turning it off.